# Default values in a function for Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, default-value

The output of the below 2 functions are the same. However I wanted to know if the second code can be used as an alternative to the first. Or is there any difference between the default values of the list

```
Code 1:
def revisedExtendList(val , list = None):
    if list is None:
        list = []
    list.append(val)
    return list

newlist1 = revisedExtendList(10)
newlist2 = revisedExtendList(123,[])
newlist3 = revisedExtendList('a')

print("\nNew list1 = {}".format(newlist1))
print("New list2 = {}".format(newlist2))
print("New list3 = {}".format(newlist3)) 

Code 2: 

def revisedExtendList(val):
    list = []
    list.append(val)
    return list

newlist1 = revisedExtendList(10)
newlist2 = revisedExtendList(123)
newlist3 = revisedExtendList('a')

print("\nNew list1 = {}".format(newlist1))
print("New list2 = {}".format(newlist2))
print("New list3 = {}".format(newlist3))
```

Comment: The difference is you can't pass in your own list in function 2.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. The second one only ever accepts a single argument, and it always returns a list with a single element. The second will do that if you pass only a single argument, but if you pass something to the `list` param then it will *mutate* that object and return it (not really a great way to go about it, honestly)